# String.format Not Aligning Correctly

Tags: java, formatting, alignment

I need to display a list of food and drinks on a bill with their prices from an array and would like to align everything. I almost have it working but needs improvements. Below is the code and a screenshot of the output. Any ideas how to make all prices aligned? So far some work but some don't. Thanks in advance.

```
public JTextArea getBillList ()
    {
        String billFormat = "";
        JTextArea billArea = new JTextArea();
        billArea.append(String.format("%-30s %30s\n\n","Name","Price"));

        for(Meal i : billList) {
            billFormat += String.format("%-30s €%30s\n",i.getName(), i.getPrice());
            billArea.append(billFormat);
            billFormat = "";
        }

        billArea.append("\nTotal Price: €" + billTotal);
        billArea.setEditable(false);
        return billArea;
    }
```

The output is this, it looks a bit crazy to me, can't make any sense of why it's pushing things around the place.

[Output From Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbzoG.png)

Comment: Use a fixed-width font.

Comment: Exactly, `Font.MONOSPACED` is the Font that you want to use. Closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. Got it solved.